# How to modify response using Interception?

Tags: angular, interception

I use the following interception in Angular:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
      map((event: any) => {
        if (event.body.data) {
          return event.body.data;
        }
      }));
```

My JSON response contains data property. So I try to return it: `return event.body.data;`.

**My service is:**

```
public get(): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get(environment.serverUrl + 'events');
}
```

**Using service:**

```
this.serviceEbents.get().subscribe(response => {
     console.log(response);
});
```

Problem is:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at MapSubscriber.project (RequestInterception.ts:43)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next
```

Therefore I dont get `console.log(response);`.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? looks fine

Comment: Interception doesn't make sense unless *all* of your responses will have those properties. Also note that `Observable<any>` isn't a very helpful signature for the consumers!

Comment: How to be, I dont understand what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HttpClient already returns just body of the response, if you want to receive the full response, and thereby necessitate getting the body using `response.body` then you need to 'observe the response' described here https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

your service would look like

```
public get(): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get(environment.serverUrl + 'events', { observe: 'response' });
}
```

otherwise just say `return event`

also you should console.log the `event` to debug this issue.

Comment: I want to get only body and reduce body by property `data`. data: [] to get simple: []

Comment: So, that why I try to use map in interceptions to reduce by `data`